# Determine if char is in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to do a custom mention system using Quill and i need to figure out how can i determine if a given char is in the alphabet or not.

Example:

I have this string: `Hello my @name is Luis` and this function which takes the position of the cursor and evaluate the word to check if it contains `@`:

```
CheckWord = function(quill, start){
    let at = false, c_char;
    for(var i = start; i > 0; --i){
        c_char = quill.getText(i, 1);
        if (c_char == '@') {
            if (quill.getText(i-1, 1) == ' ' || quill.getText(i-1, 1) == '') {
                at = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (c_char == ' ') {
            at = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return at;
}
```

Everything is working fine but in

```
 if (c_char == ' ') {
     at = false;
     break;
 }
```

I need to verify if **is not** a alphabet char (A,B,C,D, ect...)

I know that with a regex like this `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` i can achieve what i want but i dont know how  to implement it just to check if the given letter is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to test if the character is an alphabet (a-z or A-Z), just negate this if you want to match other characters than alphabets:

```
if (/[a-z]/i.test(c_char)) {
    at = false;
    break;
}
```

The `i` in the regex means case insensitive search (think of `i` as `i`nsensitive), i.e. it checks for both lowercase and uppercase letters. Since `c_char` is a single character, you don't need the `^` (beginning of input) and `$` (end of input) characters in the regex.